# GA360 - SFMC integration - leveraging activity/subscriber ID in GA360

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, google-analytics

Using the GA360 integration with Journey Builder, the system passes through, among other attributes, *sfmc_id* (to map to Subscriber ID and identify contacts) and *activity_id* (to map to the specific message in the Journey).

According to the setup help box, these two properties are:

> recognized by Google Analytics 360 as a custom dimension named Activity ID

[image]

In GA360 though I can't seem to find this dimension anywhere. Does it have to be manually created, and if so, what is the implication of the system saying it's named 'Activity ID'?

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about the GA360 integration from both vendors here:
 - **Google**: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9250031?hl=en 
 - **Salesforce**: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_google_analytics_integration_tracking.htm&type=5 

In summary, the SFMC_ID attribute (Always %%_SubscriberID%%) is what Google Analytics uses to connect to Salesforce Marketing Cloud for pushing audiences.

Assuming you've connected Google and Salesforce accounts (per the above documentation), then you should be able to [create Audiences in GA360](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_create_ga_audience.htm&type=5) where Salesforce Marketing Cloud is the "Audience Destination". Google has also documented the [Audience Creation steps here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611404?hl=en).

Audience only push into SFMC once per day, so you will need to wait until they appear in Contact Builder's "Synchronized" Data Sources before you can use them. [Trailhead has a great module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/google-analytics-360-integration-for-marketing-cloud/explore-analytics-360-audience-activation) that explains how to share GA360 data to your other Business Units.

Once the audience data has been shared to your destination Business Unit, you can use it as a [Journey Entry Source in Journey Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_ga_360_.htm&type=5).

Regarding the Custom Dimension, it is not created by default - however you could create it and populate it as part of your pageview/GoogleAnalytics activity; which would give you some flexibility to create a Big-Query data activity. However note that Google Analytics only sends the "SFMC_ID value" back into SFMC as part of the GA360 integration - you can't append additional dimensions/data to this payload.